# No split screen option in Forza 3

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

Wiki tells me about Forza 3:

"Upon launching the game, the player is presented with a screen that gives three options. One being to launch the main menu, another being free play and the final being the Xbox LIVE Marketplace"

But I don't get these 3 options with free play. Anyone an idea why? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, I don't get free play as one of the options do therefore also no splitscreen

Comment: Do you have a legitimate copy of the game?